# Admob inside a canvas

Tags: android, canvas, admob

I have a canvas in which an admob AD is there. everything working fine. But when the program is running, to refresh the Ad onDraw is called several times, in between the drawing on the canvas is not possible. Give me some suggestions please.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand your problem well, can your explain more? and did you try anything yet?

Comment: When Ad is coming, ondraw is calling several times without our intention, so i have a clickable event where onTouch is listening, so that time when Ad is refreshing, it is not detecting the touch..

Comment: can you post some codes ?

Comment: Post your layout and post the relevant code